# Adapting jQuery UI dialog box for iOS devices

Tags: jquery, iphone, ios, modal-dialog, jquery-ui-dialog

I am using jQuery UI to create a dialog that displays when a user clicks on a mailto link. In short, the dialog confirms the user accepts the terms before proceeding. Unfortunately, on the iPhone, the dialog is too small, and it does not stay centered on the screen if the user has previously zoomed in.

Here's the code:

```
...
    .dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        title: 'Disclaimer',
        resizable: false,
        width: 500,
        modal: true,
        position: 'top+10%',
        buttons:            
            {
    "Accept": function() {
      $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      window.location.href="mailto:"info@example.com;"
      },
    "Cancel": function() {
      $( this ).dialog( "close" ); }
 }
 });

$('.email-address').click(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
    $dialog.dialog('open');
    $('.ui-dialog :button').blur();
});
});
```

I'm trying to figure out the best way to address this issue. Ideally, I'd like the dialog to fill up most of the screen and always be centered even if the user is zoomed in (i.e., I don't want the dialog to ever be cut off when displayed). Alternatively, I'd like the dialog to behave as a native dialog box on the iPhone. If I do the latter, will it be necessary to create a separate script that will only run when viewed on a smart phone?

Any thoughts on the best way to accomplish either of these goals would be much appreciated.